# How to check if the datepicker and timepicker elements are set using JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I have 2 date picker and 2 respective time pickers in HTML page. 
So basically, whenever user clicks and selects any single datepicker(and/or timepicker)a function will be caled and it will check if all the 4 respective fields have values within them.

How can I achieve this using JS/jQuery?

This is my HTML code:

```
 <input type="text" id="from-datepicker"/>
    <input class="timepicker" name="timepicker" id="from-timepicker"/>

 <input type="text" id="to-datepicker"/>
    <input class="timepicker" name="timepicker" id="to-timepicker"/>
```

Comment: This looks like a "do it for me". What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have two inputs with the same name.

Secondly, you should add events to the elements. Here is a list of [DOM Events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) and [jQuery events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/) that can be triggered for a ton of purposes.

In your particular scenario, you need to check if the value has changed for them. You can use the [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) DOM event.

[JS change event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange_addeventlistener):

```js
elem = document.getElementById("id");
elem.addEventListener("change", yourFunction);
```

[jQuery.change](https://api.jquery.com/change/):

```js
$("#id").change(function() {
    // some code
});
```

Now, if you want to see if the input has a value to it, your function should look like this:

```js
$("#id").change(function() {
    // this = the element for which the event was triggered
    if($(this).val() != "") {
        // code if empty
    } else {
       // code if not empty
    }
});
```